# Change property other function

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I want to change a property inside the buttonTapped function using the newGameButton function. For example: I want to change background color but not change newGame button, I want to change the background color of the buttons connected with the buttonTapped button. Sorry about my English

```
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!


    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.getrandomColor()
        sender.tintColor = UIColor.white
        sender.isEnabled = false




@IBAction func newGameButton(_ sender: Any) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the newGameButton isn't part of the `buttons` array you can do

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (buttons.contains(sender) {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.getrandomColor()
        sender.tintColor = UIColor.white
        sender.isEnabled = false 
    }
}
```

And when starting a new game

```
@IBAction func newGameButton(_ sender: Any) {
    //reset all buttons
    buttons.forEach { button in
        button.backgroundColor = //set default background color
        button.tintColor = //set default tint color
        button.isEnabled = true
        // any other settings
    }
}
```

Comment: And, how I control in newGameButton function?

Comment: Control what? I don't see this in your question so you need to clarify it.

Comment: I want to change some property of buttonTapped function in newGameButton function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the properties of "buttonTapped" using "newGameButton",you just need to create an outlet for the "buttonTapped".You can access the properties of the "buttonTapped" using this outlet.

```
  @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func newGame(_ sender: Any) {

         buttons[0].backgroundColor = .red
    buttons[0].tintColor = .black
    }
```

Comment: But I already have an outlet collection for buttonTapped. I have 16 button. So I created outlet collection for buttonTapped

Comment: I updated above code.You can use tags for the button.Suppose the tag for "buttonTapped" is 0 , the above code will work

Comment: for i in 0 ... 16 { buttons[i].backgroundColor = .red
    buttons[i].tintColor = .black}

Comment: are you trying to change properties of one button or all button

Comment: I am trying to change properties of  all button

Comment: It should work,Did you put tags for all the buttons in storyboard